# Is the limit of a recursively defined sequence always a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$  for all natural numbers $n$, where $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  And suppose that $(x_n)$ converges to some real number $x$.  Then my question is, is it necessarily true that $f(x)=x$?

Clearly it's true if $f$ is continuous, since $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ and $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}\rightarrow x$.  But what about the general case?

Comment: You can cook up examples with a discontinuity at the limit. How about $x_1=1$, $f(t)=t/2$ for $t>0$ and $f(t)=-1$ for $t\le 0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I just-posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3425241/71829

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$f$ is merely "a function"?  Sure.  Take your favorite case where you have a continuous function $f$, and convergence to a fixed point $c$, then change the value $f$ at that one point $c$, so that it is no longer a fixed point..

Example... $f(x) = x/2$ for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) = \pi$.  Then $x_n = 1/2^n$ satisfies $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ and $x_n \to 0$, but $0$ is not a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: why are you saying "sure"???

Comment: I just-posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3425241/71829