# Is the limit of a recursively defined ordinal-indexed sequence always a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory, ordinals, nets

Let $(x_\alpha)$ be a net of real numbers indexed by the class of ordinals, satisfying the following conditions:

1. $x_{\alpha+1}=f(x_\alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$, where $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$
2. $x_\beta = {\lim}_{\alpha<\beta}(x_\alpha)$ for all limit ordinals $\beta$
3. $(x_\alpha)$ converges to $x$ for some real number $x$.

Then my question is, is it necessarily true that $f(x)=x$?  It's clearly true if $f$ is continuous, but what about the general case?

And if it is true, is it also true for nets indexed by ordinals less than some sufficiently large ordinal, like $\omega_1$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$ (assuming the axiom of choice)?  This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3425196/71829), by the way.

Comment: Net $(x_\alpha)$ in $\mathbb R$ indexed by the class of all ordinals, and 3. $x_\alpha$ converges to $x$ ... then $x_\alpha=x$ for all ordinals beyond some point.  [Use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is first-countable.]  Then from 1. we conclue $f(x) = x$.  So we did not use 2. at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for a kind of dumb reason.  At limit ordinals of uncountable cofinality, condition (2) will never hold except in trivial cases.  Indeed, if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $\alpha_n<\beta$ such that $|x_{\alpha}-x_\beta|<1/n$ for all $\alpha\geq\alpha_n$.  If $\beta$ has uncountable cofinality, then $\sup_n\alpha_n<\beta$, and we must have $x_\alpha=x_\beta$ for all $\alpha$ such that $\sup_n\alpha_n\leq \alpha<\beta$.  That is, $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\beta}$ is eventually constant, and in particular this means $f(x_\beta)=x_\beta$.

In particular, taking $\beta=\omega_1$, this shows that you must reach a fixed point at some countable ordinal.

There's nothing particularly important about $\mathbb{R}$ here--the same argument would work in any first countable $T_1$ space.  Or, it would work in any $T_1$ space if you replace "uncountable cofinality" with "cofinality greater than the minimum size of a neighborhood base at each point".

Comment: OK interesting, so the problem becomes trivial for $\omega_1$.  But it's less trivial for countable ordinals, so let me ask this: does there exist a countable ordinal $\gamma$ such that $x_{\alpha+1}=f(x_\alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$, $x_\beta = {\lim}_{\alpha<\beta}(x_\alpha)$ for all limit ordinals $\beta<\gamma$, and ${\lim}_{\alpha<\gamma}(x_\alpha) = x$ always implies that $f(x)=x$?  Or for any $\gamma$ can you always find a function that's a counterexample?

Comment: There's always a counterexample: for instance, there is a continuous order-preserving embedding of $\gamma+1$ into $\mathbb{R}$ (easy to prove by induction on $\gamma$), and so you can have $f$ take each point of the image of the embedding to the next one.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: By the way, does this argument work for the hyperreal numbers?  Are they a first countable $T_1$ space?

Comment: Is that parenthetical an important point here?  If as in my question we have a net indexed by the class of all ordinals, does that change things?

Comment: A net indexed by the ordinals can converge, but if you require it to be continuous as in your question then it will already be forced to stabilize before it reaches $\omega$.

Comment: Well, in my question I said "It's clearly true if f is continuous, but what about the general case?"  So if $f$ is an arbitrary function and you have a net indexed by ordinals in the hyperreals, will there be stabilization?

Comment: When I said continuous I was referring to the net itself (i.e., your condition (2)), not to $f$.

Comment: I don't understand, how would condition 2, which is about limit ordinals, force a net in the hyperreals to stabilize before it reaches $\omega$?

Comment: Well how else will condition 2 hold for $\beta=\omega$?

Comment: Can't you have a net start with $1,1/2,1/3, 1/4, ...$ and then all condition 2 would imply for $\beta=\omega$ is $x_\omega=0$?

Comment: No, there are lots of surreal numbers that are less than $1/n$ for each $n$ but greater than $0$.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question: ‪https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453762/71829‬

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have only just realized that in your previous questions you were talking about hyperreals, not surreals.  All the answers I gave in the comments above were about surreal numbers, not hyperreals.  For the hyperreals there is not any one universally accepted definition so you need to say exactly what you mean by hyperreals before the questions can have an answer.  (But, they will at least not be first-countable for most definitions.)

Comment: For hyperreals defined as countable ultrapowers of the reals it is still true that condition (2) forces the net to stabilize before it reaches $\omega$ (and then condition (1) forces it to remain at the constant value thereafter).  This will be true more generally for any countably saturated totally ordered set.